# Open a background with transition

Tags: jquery

I'm developing website with little bit of Jquery but...
I have found something to show the body background when a div is hover. It work perfectly. But it's without any animation. I want a little fade animation to not scare away visitors. I have tried Fadein and animate, and it doesn't work...

This is the code working perfectly. **I don't really know how to add this basic "appears" transition.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Preload
$('<img/>').hide().attr('src', 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3YtwFdb01YI/TnCNSc1c93I/AAAAAAAAA5c/V6g_3ghlw30/s1600/Background+13.jpg').load(function(){
    $('body').append($(this));
});

$('#fb').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3YtwFdb01YI/TnCNSc1c93I/AAAAAAAAA5c/V6g_3ghlw30/s1600/Background+13.jpg")');
}, function() {
    $('body').css('background', '');
});
```

});

**IT WILL HELP TO UNDERSTAND: http://jsfiddle.net/kGgyY/98/**
Thanks for helping me, and sorry for my english.

Redbean,

Comment: some html to go with it would help.. but i think what you're looking for is a slideToggle effect

Comment: Check that: http://jsfiddle.net/kGgyY/98/ Thanks for helping me! Just transition effect to be less brutal for the visitor eyes.

Comment: no problem its after 9pm here in Ireland what time is it your time? its just sometimes a time diff causes delay in communication with users. I'll take a look now

Comment: 10pm in France. Oh, okay! Ok, thanks :-)

Comment: Ah bien! Mon pere habite a Bergerac!

Comment: Je connais! Sud-ouest de la France

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle out, http://jsfiddle.net/194Ld5zo/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#fb').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.wrapper').fadeIn(500);       
    });

    $('#fb').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.wrapper').hide();
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<h1><a href="" id="fb">Hover here</a></h1>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-repeat: repeat;
}

#fb {
top: 0;
position: absolute;
}

.wrapper {
display: none;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3YtwFdb01YI/TnCNSc1c93I/AAAAAAAAA5c/V6g_3ghlw30/s1600/Background+13.jpg");
}
```

It kind of does what you want except the background-image is attached to a div instead of the body.

EDIT: Here's another one (http://jsfiddle.net/kGgyY/143/) that doesn't change your javascript file at all, I just simply added the following css:

```
body {

background-image: url("http://rs664.pbsrc.com/albums/vv4/TSAnanth/Blank%20Page/B9EAE5A5.jpg~c200");
 background-size: cover;
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;

}
```

The background-image given in the css is just a blank image.

Comment: The fiddle 143 was the solution ! :-D Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I did a `slide toggle` on it but it wasn't as effective as i thought

but this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/up6e0w34/

I don't think you can go slower than 'slow' in slidetoggle, but its good for paragraph text and stuff

I do think that the fadeIn (that you said you tried?) is more effective - perhaps you just didn't slow it down enough. Mine is set to 1000ms (1 sec), but you can slow this down further

http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jkvkycvw/

Hope this helps

Rachel

p.s. Bonne nuit!

by the way, it's quite a dark image; if you wanted to fade it out a bit you could always apply a filter to lower the opacity like in this fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/torunyx5/1/

this is the fade-in snippet

```js
$("#tog").hover(function(e) {
  $("#fb").fadeIn("1000");
});

/* slide toggle
$("#tog").hover(function(e) {
  $("#fb").slideToggle("slow");
});
*/
```

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
}

#fb {
  background: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3YtwFdb01YI/TnCNSc1c93I/AAAAAAAAA5c/V6g_3ghlw30/s1600/Background+13.jpg') repeat;
  background-repeat: repeat!important;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="tog">Hover here</h3>
<div id="fb">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachel !